# Overwritting border for active li doesn't work when fixed menu has overflow-y

Tags: html, css

So, I want to have a simple menu with a `border-right` of 1 px black. And then, I want the active li to override the `border-right` to `1px white`. My code works, except when I add an `overflow-y: scroll` to my fixed menu.

Here you can see what I mean, there's a fixed menu that's scrollable but the active styling doesn't take effect. If you comment the overflow-y line, you'll see the active styling does work then.

https://jsfiddle.net/6bd4b6ty/2/

```css
.menu{
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  position: fixed;
  overflow-y: scroll; /* comment this line */
}

ul{
  list-style: none;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li{
  height: 40px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  width: 100px;
}

a{
  height: 40px;
  width: 100px;
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

a.active{
  border-right: 1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a class="active">potato</a></li>
    <li><a>cheese</a></li>
    <li><a>tomato</a></li>
    <li><a>cucumber</a></li>
    <li><a>carrot</a></li>
    <li><a>garlic</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Any ideas on how to solve this, obviously I want the menu to be scrollable at the same time that the active border works :P Thanks!

Comment: The style does apply.  The reason you aren't seeing the border is because the scrollbar width isn't taken into account, and thus it is obscured by the scrollbar -- but the right does have a white border. !!!

Comment: sigh... if only  `::-webkit-scrollbar` would have cross-browser support.

Answer (score 2):

Don't fix width for the menu, set it to auto

See it working, I changed the active border-color to red for visiblility

```css
.menu{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width:auto;
    height: 200px;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    position: fixed;
    /* overflow:visible; */
    overflow-y: scroll; /* comment this line */
}

ul{
  list-style: none;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li{
  height: 40px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  width: 100px;
}

a{
  height: 40px;
  width: 100px;
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}

a.active{
  border-right: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
  <li><a class="active">potato</a></li>
  <li><a>cheese</a></li>
  <li><a>tomato</a></li>
  <li><a>cucumber</a></li>
  <li><a>carrot</a></li>
  <li><a>garlic</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: that doesn't work, it just adds the border next to the parent border :|

Comment: sorry, I didn't get that completely. Did you run the snippet in my answer. the red border? ok. please tell me what is missing in it?

Comment: I' extremely sorry for misunderstanding and not noticing it earlier.

Comment: The problem is that moving the border-right to the a tag, means that the rest of the menu (other items out of the ul) won't have that border-right... but maybe it's better if I just add border-right to each element separately...

Answer (score 2):

Using `:after` selector you can achieve this

```css
.menu{ 
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: auto;
  height: 200px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  position: fixed;
  overflow-y: scroll; /* comment this line */
}
.menu:after{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  width:1px;
  height:123%;
  background:#000;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 0;
}
ul{
  list-style: none;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  z-index:1;
}

li{
  height: 40px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  width: 100px;

}

a{
  height: 40px;
  width: 100px;
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  // border-right: 1px solid black;
}

a.active{
  border-right: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
  <li><a class="active">potato</a></li>
  <li><a>cheese</a></li>
  <li><a>tomato</a></li>
  <li><a>cucumber</a></li>
  <li><a>carrot</a></li>
  <li><a>garlic</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: the menu contains many other things... other than this <ul>, you've given me an idea on a workaround though! but why doesn't this work, any clue?

Comment: Update my answer with adding border in .menu using `:after` selector

Answer (score 1):

Please change the code as shown below. My edits are commented. The explanation is below the code snippet.

```css
.menu{
  /*border-right: 1px solid black;*/ /* I deleted this line*/
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  position: fixed;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

ul{
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%; /* Changed from px to % */
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li{
  height: 40px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%; /* Changed from px to % */
}

a{
  border-right: 1px solid black; /* I added this*/
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%; /* Changed from px to % */
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

a.active{
  border-right: 1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a class="active">potato</a></li>
    <li><a>cheese</a></li>
    <li><a>tomato</a></li>
    <li><a>cucumber</a></li>
    <li><a>carrot</a></li>
    <li><a>garlic</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

## CHANGES

### First Change

Remove the `border-right` from `.menu` class. And add the same `border-right` to `a` tag.

### Second Change

In three places, the `px` is changed to `%`.

## EXPLANATION

### For First Change

The `.main` has width of `100px`. When the horizontal scrollbar appears the width of `.main` will be `100px` including the scrollbar. That is the reason the `border-right` comes after the scrollbar.

To eliminate this, remove the `border-right` from `.main` and add the `border-right` to `a` tag.

### For Second Change

The reason for the appearing of vertical scrollbar, even though the width of all the child element is same, is as follows:

Since the horizontal scrollbar is appeared some content of the child is gone under that horizontal scrollbar. To view these contents, a vertical scrollbar is required.

By making the `px` to `%`, the remaining width (i.e. width of `.main` minus horizontal scrollbar width) will be considered as `100%`, thus we can eliminate this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The border appearing after scrollbar is a strange behavior.

But if you want a work-around to get the final output. Check the shared code snippet below.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* browser reset code */
}
.menu {
  width: 100px;
  height: calc(40px * 6);
  /* actual height of UL */
  padding: 0;
  border-right: 1px solid red;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.grand-parent {
  width: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 200px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.parent {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 200px;
  width: 125px;
  /* width + approx scrollbar width */
}
li {
  height: 40px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  width: 100px;
}
a {
  height: 40px;
  width: 100px;
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
a.active {
  border-right: 1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div class="grand-parent">
  <div class="parent">
    <ul class="menu">
      <li><a class="active">potato</a>
      </li>
      <li><a>cheese</a>
      </li>
      <li><a>tomato</a>
      </li>
      <li><a>cucumber</a>
      </li>
      <li><a>carrot</a>
      </li>
      <li><a>garlic</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Working [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/6bd4b6ty/3/) !!!

Remove border style in menu and add into li elements.

```
li{
  border-right: 2px solid blue;
  height: 40px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  width: 100px;
}
li .active{
  border-right: 2px solid white!important; 
  /* border-right: 2px inset #fff!important; */
}
```